# having 2 different styles for ui-state-default and ui-selected

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

at the moment, i am using the `selectable` JQUERY function

```
<style>
  #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
</style>


<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

but for some reason, when i select an element, the color will not change to bright orange but revert to the default gray of `ui-state-default` like below:

[image: incorrect color of selected element]

But if I go to the Chrome debugger and uncheck the background in ui-state-default in the style section, it works perfectly.

[image: unchecking background of ui-state-default in Chrome debugger]

[image: correct color of selected and unselected elements]

Is it because of this snippet:

```
var nodes = document.getElementById('selectable').getElementsByClassName('ui-widget-content');  
      if (nodes.length > 0)
      {
        nodes[0].innerHTML = getSymbol();
        nodes[0].setAttribute("class", "ui-state-default");
      }
```

How do i go around this problem, such that when i click on the element of interest, the color will change like i specified in the `<style>` tag.

Comment: You're already using jQuery, so use $ instead of  document.getElementById

Comment: @Diodeus could you give me more details please as to how it can directly answer the question

Comment: Hopefully my answer below helps. If now, let me know.

Comment: When and how is the faulted snippet called?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, this is quite simple.

`$('.ui-widget-content')` will select all of your LI elements. (alternately you could use `$('#selectable li')`)

```
$('.ui-widget-content').click(function() {
      $(.'ui-widget-content').removeClass('.ui-state-default'); <-- this clears previous selections
      $(this).addClass('.ui-state-default'); <-- this adds the class to the clicked item
})
```

Comment: hmm, it didn't quite work..the ui-state-default seems to be dominant for some reason.